# Selenium javascript broken image

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, selenium

I'm trying to check which images are broken:https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/broken_images, I found all the images:

```
await driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/broken_images");

     let elements = await driver.findElements(By.css(".example>img"));

        for (const element of elements) {
            let height = await element.getAttribute("height");
            
            console.log(el);
        }
```

, but all heights are the same, how to check the status of the code?

Comment: *console.log(height);
Where can I find the proper documentation for selenium js

Comment: When you get the height you're getting the height of the image from the page DOM. It's always the same because all the images are the same height. You'll want to capture the src `.getAttribute("src");`of the image, send a GET request to that location and verify the status is `200` - see here for samples: https://livecodestream.dev/post/5-ways-to-make-http-requests-in-javascript/  - I'm not set up  in js to create code block for you so i can't help beyond that link